# Batch: How can i skip it if there is no input?

Tags: batch-file

so in this code

```
:chat
cls
findstr /v "sdlkfjsdlkfs98dfu9sd8f6ysd954" \\Cap\FileServer\Recive\chatroom.chatfile
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo.
color 0b

goto chat1

:chat1
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
set /p text=Text:
echo %name% : %text% >>\\Cap\FileServer\Recive\chatroom.chatfile
goto chat
```

So i was wondering if i can make it not wait for the Text: and go on to refreshing the chat file if there is no input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with Batch as once you have prompted the user, the execution will wait until input is received.

Perhaps as a workaround, you can "refresh" when empty input is received:

```
:chat
cls
findstr /v "sdlkfjsdlkfs98dfu9sd8f6ysd954" \\Cap\FileServer\Recive\chatroom.chatfile
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo.
color 0b

goto chat1

:chat1
REM Reset any existing text value.
set "text="

ping localhost -n 3 >nul
set /p text=Text:

REM Check for input.
IF NOT "%text%"=="" (
    REM Input was given. Write it to the file.
    echo %name% : %text% >>\\Cap\FileServer\Recive\chatroom.chatfile
)

goto chat
```

So in the above, if the user just presses Enter at the prompt, nothing will be written to the chatfile and the loop will start over.

Comment: With this, It just says the last thing a person says when you hit enter

Comment: @John - Right, it will not update the chatfile at all and will just re-read the file. I am assuming someone is updating this file on another machine so if they have made an update you would see it (again, without having to input anything yourself to force the refresh).